button hover state in mousarea
I want to use a Button within a MouseArea, and when the mouse moves over the button, I want both to be in a hovered state. However, when I move over the button, the MouseArea exits the hovered state because the MouseArea's signal for 'exited' is executed when the mouse moves over the button.
I want something like the image below:

Code:
Window {
    visible: true
    minimumWidth: 600
    minimumHeight: 320

    Rectangle
    {
        id: idRec1
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: itemHovered ? Qt.lighter("red", 1.5) :"red"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        property bool itemHovered: false

        MouseArea
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            hoverEnabled:true

            onEntered: idRec1.itemHovered = true
            onExited: idRec1.itemHovered = false
        }

        Button
        {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Button"
        }
    }
}


You could use a HoverHandler instead of a MouseArea.

You can solve your problem by moving your Button inside your MouseArea, i.e.
Recatangle {
    MouseArea {
        Button { }
    }
}

Or as iam_peter suggested, use HoverHandler:
Rectangle {
    HoverHandler { }
    Button { }
}

However, instead of MouseArea, I recommend using Frame or Pane, because both offer:

a hoverEnabled and hovered properties
a background property

These properties provide a visual cue for users when the mouse hovers over or enters the Frame/Pane, they adjust their geometry based on their children, and they maintain the hovered state even when the mouse moves over child elements within the Frame/Pane.
Pane {
    id: view
    implicitWidth: 350
    hoverEnabled: true
    property int indent: 40
    property string text: "New View1"
    background: Rectangle { color: Qt.darker("#444", view.hovered ?  1.8 : 1) }
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        IconButton { Layout.leftMargin: view.indent; icon.source: "address-book.svg" }
        Label { Layout.fillWidth:true; text: view.text }
        RowLayout {
            visible: view.hovered
            IconButton { icon.source: "reset.svg"; ToolTip.text: "Click to start the instance" }
            IconButton { icon.source: "pencil-square.svg"; ToolTip.text: "Modify View Name" }
            IconButton { icon.source: "x.svg"; ToolTip.text: "Delete View" }
        }
    }
}

You can Try it Online!


Thank Stephen for your solution.
